# How to get a dictionary with keys equal to group members in dataframe and the values to the group ids?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follwos:

```
       City     Name
0   Seattle    Alice
1   Seattle      Bob
2  Portland  Mallory       
3  Portland      Bob
```

I have used df.groupby('City') and for the above example we would have 2 groups, i.e., 1)Seattle 2)Portland. Now I want to get a dictionary for which the keys are names and the values are group ids, i.e.:

```
dict = {'Alice': {'1'}, 'Bob': {'1','2'}, 'Mallory': {'2'}}
```

What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: I do not understand where the values in your dict are coming from, could you please explain your logic?

Comment: How weird that you `groupby` on city, when you actually want the names as group titles. Look at `Pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()` for this.

Answer (score 0):

This code will get you a list as the entry in the dictionary for each name:

```
    array = df.data
    names = array[:,2] # slice out the names
    places = array[:,1] #slice out the places
    places = [list(set(places)).index(place) for place in places] #convert the places to ints
    pairs = zip(names,places) #combine the lists
    dict = {}
    for name in set(names): #step through each name
        dict[name] = [x[1] for x in pairs where x[0] == name]
```

Not the prettiest code, but it should work.